# Declaring a single byte variable in Python

Tags: python, byte

How do we declare a single byte variable in Python? I would like to achieve the following result represented in C:

```
unsigned char = 0xFF;
```

I would like to know if it is possible to declare an 8-bit variable in Python.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Python doesn't differentiate between characters and strings the way C does, nor does it care about `int` bit widths. For a single byte, you basically have three choices:

1. A length 1 [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) (or [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects)) object `mychar = b'\xff'` (or `mychar = bytearray(b'\xff')`)
2. An `int` that you don't assign values outside `range(256)` (or use masking to trim overflow): `mychar = 0xff`
3. A [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_ubyte) type, e.g. `mychar = ctypes.c_ubyte(0xff)`

The final option is largely for dealing with C functions through `ctypes`, it's otherwise slow/not Pythonic. Choosing between options 1 and 2 depends on what you're using it for; different use cases call for different approaches (though indexing/iterating the `bytes` object would get you the `int` values if you need to use both forms).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on python version.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, May  6 2020, 12:04:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> myba = bytes([0])
>>> myba[0]
0
>>> 
$ python 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar 20 2020, 17:08:22) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> myba = bytes([0])
>>> myba[0] 
'['
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the python version.

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar 20 2020, 17:08:22) ...
>>> myba = bytes([0])
>>> myba[0] 
'['
>>> myba = bytearray([0])
>>> myba[0]
0
>>> 
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, May  6 2020, 12:04:35) ...
>>> myba = bytes([0])
>>> myba[0]
0
>>> myba = bytearray([0])
>>> myba[0]
0
>>>
```